# How to update document with dynamic fields in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Assume that I have a document in database which has the following structure;

```
id: 1,
name: alex,
age: 21
```

There are some updates in client side and the same document with `id:1` returns as;

```
id: 1,
name: alex,
age: 21,
location: usa
```

where a new field `location` is added.

I want to update the document in database. I want to add this new inserted field but I couldn't find out how can I handle this situation. Because `location` is not static, it can be `surname`, `job` and so on. So new inserted fields are dynamic and I don't know in advance.

If the field `location` was static, I could write a query as;

```
db.collection("user").updateOne( {id: 1},
                     {$set: {name: "alex", age: "21", location: "usa"}}, function(err, result){
     if(err){} 
     else{}
});
```

But now, how can I update the document with this newly added fields?

Comment: So your question seems to be more about how do you query, rather than how do you update?  inserting the document is no different than any other time unless you're enforcing schemas via mongoose or similar.

Comment: But I was setting the fields as in the example. Now, how can I set them? I don't know the fields in advance. I couldn't update document with id :1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are saying that you have an updated object:

```
id: 1,
name: alex,
age: 21,
location: usa
```

then I assume that you have some object that has a value of:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'alex',
  age: 21,
  location: 'usa'
}
```

e.g. as a result of parsing this JSON sent from the client:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "alex",
  "age": 21,
  "location": "usa"
}
```

If you have that object in a variable called `object` then all you have to do is:

```
db.collection("user")
  .updateOne({id: object.id}, {$set: object}, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      // handle success
    } else {
      // handle success
    }
});
```

But most likely you will need to use `_id` instead of `id`:

```
db.collection("user")
  .updateOne({_id: object._id}, {$set: object}, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      // handle success
    } else {
      // handle success
    }
});
```

If you want to be able to remove properties as well then maybe even:

```
db.collection("user")
  .replaceOne({_id: object._id}, object, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      // handle success
    } else {
      // handle success
    }
});
```

I wouldn't recommend putting data into the database without at least some sort of validation but it's possible to do what you're asking about in the way shown above.

For more info see:

- [Update Specific Fields](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/node/update/#update-specific-fields)
- [Replace a Document](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/node/update/#replace-a-document)

in the [Introduction to MongoDB in Node.js](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/node/introduction/).